# Reading packets from InputStream - Proper design

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

Developing an Android application that communicates over Bluetooth in a client/server architecture. The actual implementation isn't relevant but I was wondering the about the most appropriate design for handling an Input/OutputStream.

At the moment the server side runs a listener in a separate thread, reading the InputStream and constructing a corresponding packet from the stream based on the first received byte. These constructed packets are pushed into a buffer to be handled by another thread which parses the packets and determines what action to take.

This is more a question regarding proper technique/design of a communication protocol. I'm wondering if there are any alternative ways to process incoming data over a stream. I realize this is highly dependent on the application, however I have the inclination that there are multiple methods to handling stream data that would be just as applicable.

Rather an ambiguous question, even a reference to some text that has relevant information regarding proper object oriented communication design would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> At the moment the server side runs a listener in a separate thread,
>   reading the InputStream and constructing a corresponding packet from
>   the stream based on the first received byte. These constructed packets
>   are pushed into a buffer to be handled by another thread which parses
>   the packets and determines what action to take.

I believe this isn't very efficient in terms of multithreading. Parsing packet header is not a very time-consuming operation. I suggest your primary thread not only to handle stream reading, but also to parse packet headers and push packets into relevant buffers, which can be simultaneously processed.

But since your question is too broad (I think actual implementation or, rather, actual task you are trying to fulfill and requirements are matter very much here), this may also seem inefficient.

Comment: Exactly. Two threads parsing the same data from the same connection is just waste.